# Get the data from a array and arrange it to different structure of JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have a array and I need to get the data from that array and arrange a new array with different structure.

**Array what I have**

```
[[21,1],[22,2],[32,4],[35,6],[45,1],[82,1]]
```

**Array what I need**

```
[[0-10,0],[10-20,0],[20-30,3],[30-40,10],[40-50,1],[80-90,1] ]
```

can we do it using JavaScript?

Comment: btw jQuery has little to do with this. --- Firstly, please edit the question and include a [mcve] of what you have tried so far? Secondly, please explain how the input and output related to each other?

Comment: Can you please define what your different structure is meant to be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide the range value by ten and add the count value

```js
const
    data = [[21, 1], [22, 2], [32, 4], [35, 6], [45, 1], [82, 1]],
    result = data.reduce((r, [v, c]) => {
        const i = Math.floor(v / 10);
        while (r.length <= i) r.push([`${r.length * 10}-${(r.length + 1) * 10 - 1}`, 0]);
        r[i][1] += c;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can we change this into [[0-9,0],[10-19,0],[20-29,3],[30-39,10],[40-49,1],[80-89,1] ]